# Use SKU and Product Name as Meta Title

Tags: magento

I need to update my Magento product details (over 25000 of them) so they all have Meta Title details set in the following way:

Product SKU : Product Name

Can someone help me work out how to programatically update the database so this is done on every product please?

Currently on Magento 1.4.0.1, but about to launch our upgraded 1.6 site.

Comment: Hm, where in your code are you stuck? Usually this is just loading a product collection, looping thru the products one by one, changing the `meta_title` attribute value to what you want and save the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Jürgen Thelen says:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToSelect('name');
foreach ($products as $product) {
  $product->setMetaTitle(sprintf("%s : %s", $product->getSku(), $product->getName()));
  $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I need to build it into a complete script in order to run it against the database. I can probably sort this out but will shout back if I need any further help. Much appreciated!!